# New orientation methods not getting called in ios6

Tags: objective-c

Orientation methods are not getting called in the latest version of xcode 4.5

```
(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    // Override point for customization after application launch.    

    self.sampleController =[[SampleViewController alloc]init];

    UINavigationController * nvC =[[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:self.sampleController];

    self.window.rootViewController =nvC;

    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;

}

(BOOL)shouldAutorotate{
    return YES;
}
(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations{
       return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}
```

when i take UIViewController object as windows rootviewcontroller,Its getting called properly.But,when i take UINavigationController object  as windows rootviewcontroller,Its not getting called.

Would any one please help me on this.

Answer (score 0):

You may make the new controller as sub view of UINavigationController and implement the callback methods in it. then use the controller as window's rootviewcontroller.
Or you can also use category to implement the methods if you don't like create new class.

Comment: No.Just i have created a view controller and added to UINavigationController's rootviewcontroller and then have added UINavigationController object to windows rootviewcontroller.And orientation callbacks i have implemented in view controller class.